# Maximise div[data-role=content] in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Has anyone actually succeeded in doing this it seems like there are so many attempts on line but no one has a definite solution. I've tried plugins that a lot of people suggested but nothing is working.

I just want to have a Google Map go full dimensions (apart from header and footer) and then on another page I want a div to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery-Mobile content area 100% height between head and foot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445977/jquery-mobile-content-area-100-height-between-head-and-foot)

In the meantime I would recommend to use iScroll [with CSS position:fixed; for header&footer in iOS5 only]

In iScroll you just wrap the content into a wrapper & scroller class, the rest is done by the script. Here's the homepage http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 and here's some code:

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">
     <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="scroller">
           your content here.
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

For iScroll initialization use the documentation provided on cubiq's site.

zY

Comment: Keep in mind that iScroll 4 is completely nonfunctional on Windows Phone 7. This may or may not be a problem, depending on your requirements.