# Jquery Mobile content not filling 100%

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to fill out the content section with a div that is 100% the of it but the height of the content section seems to be 0. I have tried numerous times to get it working but noting seems to work. My app relies on the profile_container taking up 100% of the available height as the items inside the profile_container are scaled as percentages of it.

Here is the HTML

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="page" id="home">

   <div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
     <h1>Game On</h1>
   </div>

   <div data-role="content" data-transition="slide"> 
     <div id="profile_container">
     </div> 
   </div>

    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"> 
     <div data-role="navbar" > 
        <ul > 
            <li><a href="#home" id="home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#create" id="create" data-icon="plus">Create</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#events" id="events" data-icon="bullets">Events</a></li> 
            <li ><a href="#nearby" id="nearby" data-icon="search">Nearby</a></li> 
        </ul> 
     </div> <!-- /navbar -->
   </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#profile_container{
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px;

}
```

And here is a picture of what is happening

[image]

Can anybody help me out?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2K6r5/

Comment: Maybe have a look at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7445977/384985

Comment: Okay having a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting 100% height is done by adding :

```
html, body{height:100%;}
#profile_container{
    min-height:100%;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px;

}
```

Edit:

Check the links for more information please.

[height: 100% or min-height: 100% for html and body elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2K6r5/2/)

Comment: I made the changes but its still not working I'm afraid

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2K6r5/

Comment: Thanks for your help although it somewhat gave me what I wanted I found what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile